# Fix Spring MVC 4 Validation

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new with Spring and specially **Spring mvc**.

How can I **validate** data binding ? (For info I don't use Spring Rest)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simply validator.
Check this spring link : [enter link description here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html), it will give you all answers.

Good luck